# Angular 7 - getting error as `Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@'` how to fix this?

Tags: angular, angular7

In my `Interceptor` file, I am getting an error as :

```
ERROR in ./src/app/auth/auth.interceptor.js 8:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '@' (8:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
| import { UserService } from "./../shared/user.service";
|
> @Injectable()
| export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
|
```

How to fix this? here is my ts file:

```
import { HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpHandler, HttpEvent } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { tap } from "rxjs/operatos";
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

import { UserService } from "./../shared/user.service";

@Injectable()
export class AuthInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

    constructor(private userService:UserService, private router:Router){}

    intercept(req:HttpRequest<any>, next:HttpHandler){
        if(req.headers.get('noauth')){
            return next.handle(req.clone());
        }
        else{
            const clonedreq = req.clone({
                headers:req.headers.set('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + this.userService.getToken())
            })
            return next.handle(clonedreq).pipe(tap(event => {}, err => {
                if(err.error.auth === false ){
                    this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
                }
            } ))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong, this syntax seems valid to me in Typescript. But you seem to be using that as `javascript`: change your file extension from `js` to `ts` and the message should disappear.

Comment: Facing same issue could someone tell me how to resolve this. i don't have any webpack configuration so far. its just simple and straight forward Angular 7 app.

Comment: Open a new question with details.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68328667/module-parse-failed-unexpected-character-110-angular-7